# YouTube video blocked in a few countries, or it's not really blocked, can't tell

Tags: youtube

I want to watch a YouTube video that the uploader says has been blocked for a few countries but I don't know if it's really blocked.

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zusIIjC37uI
```

Is there any way to watch or download it? I don't actually get the "blocked" message. The space where the video is supposed to play just shows up blank instead of the sad face in a red TV box.

Could be a server hiccup?

Comment: Try TOR. It's a proxy jumper and will mask your IP to a different country/ISP. However, it's kind of slow. Are you able to take the Youtube Video URL and put it on a site like ZAMZAR where it will take the video, convert it and give you a link for downloading it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can I download this youtube video when content is blocked?](http://superuser.com/questions/290474/how-can-i-download-this-youtube-video-when-content-is-blocked)

Comment: Well, my friend says this is the link: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v­=zusIIjC37uI
but I just get blanks not the usual "video blocked with the red sad tv icon".  Will ZAMZAR work?

Comment: Does TOR choose a random country?  I know of sites that will not allow you stream their content unless a country is detected.  If you show up with no IP, it won't work.

Comment: "show up with no IP." Lol, if we could do that.. we'd have alot more hackers amongst us.

Comment: ZAMZAR doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

TOR would be painfully slow wouldn't it?

this seems pretty good.
http://www.unblockyoutube.us/

Comment: Tor would be plenty fast for youtube.

Comment: "unblock..." gives 404 error.

Comment: @verve the link definitely works.

Comment: @verve your youtube link should be http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zusIIjC37uI   (the one you posted had some strange chars put in). The link says "This video contains content from Sony Pictures Movies & Shows, who has blocked it on copyright grounds."  So it's not a country thing.

Comment: @verve  Try a search for Bo & Lauren (Lost Girl) Season 1 Episode 6  Food for thought  RECAP  there are probably a number of places with it    http://www.tv-links.eu/tv-shows/Lost-Girl_23911/season_1/episode_6/

Comment: http://saturdayseason.blogspot.com/2010/10/lost-girl-season-1-episode-6-food-for.html   ok just watched some of it, it's a mile away from the A-team.. enjoy the rubbish! lost girl!!!

Comment: Boo. It's a hilarious show.  But my friend in Australia can watch it. How did you manage to watch it?

Comment: The blog is not a recap but part of an acctual episode. My link was a recap of a specific storyline of the whole season.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1516/discussion-between-barlop-and-verve)

Comment: Please update the link to that discussion in chat. It is a dead link now.

Comment: @bgoodr I have no idea why the mods deleted that chat page or what was there.  I doubt that in this case it was anything that useful, it's possible there wasn't any discussion at all.One benefit of chat is it can stop comments overflowing so maybe when the system suggested continuation in chat I went along with it for that reason.It's possible there wasn't further discussion.I don't know why mods deleted the chat page it seems absurd of them but I am quite sure there wasn't anything important there, 'cos even comments before it are a bit light headed.

Comment: @barlop Thanks. I even checked the wayback machine (http://tinyurl.com/nrjxxf8) and that was also blocked due to "Page cannot be crawled or displayed due to robots.txt."  Duly noted that the chat discussion might be not very useful, but even more egregious is the use of the robots.txt to block getting access to it.